# Converting Excel files into geodatabase with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, excel

I have several Excel files that contain several sheets. I need to convert these files into one table in gdb. I wrote script that convert the whole sheet in separate table. How can I export a range (f.e. A8:G(rows on the sheet)) of the sheet to one table.

```py
import arcpy, os, xlrd,xlwt
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fname = 'D:/excel_files/exc4.xls'
output_gdb = "D:/P01_ExctoGDB/GDB_EXC.gdb"
# Open the workbook
rb = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)

# List sheet names, and pull a sheet by name
sheet_names = rb.sheet_names()

for i in range(0,len(sheet_names)):
    sheet=rb.sheet_by_index(i)
    val=sheet.row_values(0)[0]
    arcpy.AddMessage(val)
    vals=[sheet.row_values(8) for rownum in range(sheet.nrows)]

    outTablename= output_gdb+"/"+str(sheet_names[i]).replace(" ",'').replace(".","")
    arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(fname,outTablename, sheet_names[i])
```

Comment: You can't limit how much of the spreadsheet you convert via arcpy to the extent of my knowledge. You would have to delete rows from your GIS table post-conversion.

Comment: @EmilBrundage, yes it is good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EmilBrundage advised I just deleted first rows.

```py
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outTablename,"OBJECTID","OBJECTID >=1 AND OBJECTID <7") as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
     cursor.deleteRow()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at [Understanding how to use Microsoft Excel files in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/understanding-how-to-use-microsoft-excel-files-in-arcgis.htm) which says:

> When accessed from ArcGIS, a worksheet is shown as a table with a
>   dollar sign ($) at the end of its name, but a named range does not
>   have a dollar sign. Worksheets or named ranges with names containing
>   spaces have single quotation marks placed around the table name.

I do little with Excel files but I think it is a named range that you need to use.